# Black Screen while Building App on iOS Simulator Xcode 14.3.1

Tags: ios, build, simulator

I am trying to build my app on Xcode but every time I try to I get a black screen. I already *reviewed the ViewController, App Delegate and DetailViewController*, each of these files seem to be correct. I also *tried building my app with an older version of iOS* being iOS 15.5 but this process was not successful and finally just to make sure everything was correct in my code also *tried removing certain parts (the newest code added) of my ViewController* but it wouldn't build the app still. Has this happened to anyone of you?

I'm new to this programming and entire ecosystem in which I'm working with, also my first post here. :D

What it should happen:
It should show a table with images but it won't, just shows a plain black screen of the app.

I am  using:
Mac OS 13.4
Xcode 14.3.1

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var pictures = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
        
        for item in items {
            if item.hasPrefix("nssl") {
                pictures.append(item)
            }
            
        }
        print(pictures)
    }
    
 }
```

This is my DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    var selectedImage: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = selectedImage
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

        if let imageToLoad = selectedImage {
            imageView.image  = UIImage(named: imageToLoad)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
    }
}
```

This is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```